# Filtrando resultado por categoria

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
using (ObjectContext ctx = new ObjectContext("name=kinectEntities"))
{
    ctx.DefaultContainerName = "kinectEntities";
    ObjectSet<produtos> query = ctx.CreateObjectSet<produtos>();

    foreach (produtos r in query)
    {
        //percorrendo registros da base.. monta as parada aqui..
        var button = new KinectTileButton { Label = (r.valor).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) };
        this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
    }
};
```

Tenho esse código só que ele me retorna todos os produtos. Não sei como utilizar o where para filtrar meu resultado por categoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo, só basta sabe qual campo você vai usar para filtra.
Supondo que você tem um IdCategoria é quer filtra por IdCategoria = 1 ficaria assim;

```
var prodtutos = query.Where(p => p.IdCategoria == 1);
```

Sua query pode ser feita assim;

```
using (ObjectContext ctx = new ObjectContext("name=kinectEntities"))
{
    ctx.DefaultContainerName = "kinectEntities";
    ObjectSet<produtos> query = ctx.CreateObjectSet<produtos>();

    var prodtutos = query.Where(p => p.IdCategoria = 1);

    foreach (produtos r in prodtutos)
    {
        //percorrendo registros da base.. monta as parada aqui..
        var button = new KinectTileButton { Label = (r.valor).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) };
        this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
    }
};
```

Detalhes;

1. A query só vai ser executada quando tiver na interação do foreach,
   então até lá você pode manipular-la com mais filtros.
2. Lembre de usar o [Namespace System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: Deu um erro 
Error 2 Delegate 'System.Func<Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.produtos,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments E:\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Clean\Vitrine\Views\ArticleView.xaml.cs 54 45 Vitrine

Comment: consegiu resolver ?

Comment: Consegui sim, muito obrigado, era vacilo meu